# React.jsでコメントアウトができずアロー関数を使った表示ができない

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-jsx, next.js

React.jsでアロー関数を使って表記リストを表示しようとしています。
参考書『React.js & Next.js超入門』に掲載されていたプログラムで
[Webでサンプルコードのダウンロードができる](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/support/7980html/5692.html)ようなのですが、zipファイルの解凍でエラーが出て見れない状態です。

**問題**
①React.js部分は、Javaスクリプトなので、以下の記事を参考にすると`{// }`のコメントアウトが使えるはずですが、実行中のコードではコメントとして認識されません。

参考記事:
[React JSX コメントを書きたい！ - かもメモ](https://chaika.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/04/01/123000)

② Webブラウザでは以下のように表示されるはずですが、現行のコードを実行したところ「wait...」と表示されます。
ブラウザの更新やGoogleChrome以外でも、確認しましたが表示が変わりません。
`<div id ="root">wait...</div>`の部分のデフォルトのままということでしょうか。

表示したいもの

```
React
Google
*Googleの検索サイトです
[※Googleに移動][3 http://google.com]
```

現在表示されるもの

```
React
wait...
```

③Reactの表記について

ダブルクォート`" "`とシングルクォート`' '`の使い分けが、以下のコードでは`color: 'white',`以下がシングルになっているのですが、どのような決まりなのでしょうか。
ここはCSSでしょうか。

```
        const dfn = {
        fontSize: "20pt",
        padding: "10px",
    }
        const dt = {
        fontSize: "16pt",
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: '#006',
        padding: '10px',
    }
```

コード

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="URF-8" />
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>React</h1>
    <div id ="root">wait...</div>
    <!-- Webブラウザで表示するとdataの内容を元に「記述リスト」を作成 -->
    <script type="text/babel">
        let dom = document.querySelector('#root');

        const dfn = {
        fontSize: "20pt",
        padding: "10px",
    }
        const dt = {
        fontSize: "16pt",
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: '#006',
        padding: '10px',
    }

        const dd={
        color: 'black';,
        padding: '10px',
    }

        let data = {
        url: 'http://google.com',
        title:'Google',
        caption: '*Googleの検索サイトです'
    };

        {//JSXで<dl>タグが用意されている}
        <!--JSXで<dl>タグが用意されている-->
        let el = (
        <div>

            {(()=>

                <dl>
                    <dt style={dt}><dfn style={dfn}>
                        {data.title}
                    </dfn></dt>
                    <dd style={dd}>
                        <a href={data.url}>※{data.title}に移動</a>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                )()}
        </div>
        );

        ReactDOM.render(el, dom);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**コメントアウトにならない件について**
Sublime Textを使っており、以下のようにコメントアウトが効きません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webサンプルですが、私の方でダウンロードしましたが、問題なく解凍できました。
OS、解凍ソフトは何をお使いですか？
React JSX コメントを書きたい！ - かもメモを見ますと、// も使えるが{ }の閉じタグの前に改行が必要。と書いてあります。

```
{// 一行コメント
}
```

改行がないと、最後の}もコメントアウトされてエラーになる

```
{// 一行コメント}
```

下記のは改行がないようですが、実際のコードにも改行はないのでしょうか？

```
{//JSXで<dl>タグが用意されている}
```

Comment: MacOS Catalinaでそのままダブルクリックで解凍しています。こちらではダウンロードしてもアーカイブユーティリティでエラーが表示されて解凍できませんでした。

Comment: 改行してもコメントアウトになりませんでした。

Comment: windowsパソコンはお持ちではありませんか？windows10で問題なく解凍できています。

Comment: 実行中のコードではコメントとして認識されません。とありますが、「コメントとして認識」とはどのような動作を想定してらっしゃいますか？

Comment: windowsパソコンは持っておりません。情報いただきましてありがとうございます。「<!-- Webブラウザで表示するとdataの内容を元に「記述リスト」を作成 -->」のように文字列がグレーになることを、コメントとして認識されたと考えております。